# Return value that matches 2 or more criteria in any order

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup

I'm at a loss here and would appreciate any help!

I have a list of names and numbers.

[image: sample]

In column A, I want to return the Name with the largest Volume, that matches two or more characters from No.1 - No.3, in any order.

The numbers in No.1 - No.3 can be up to 5 digits.

I have looked for index match functions for multiple criteria, but I can only find those that match ALL the criteria.

e.g.

```
{=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D2&E2&F2,D:D&E:E&F:F,0),0)}
```

Comment: @JerryJeremiah For cell A2, I want to return B:B that match 2 or more of cells D2, E2, F2 in cells D:F. does that make sense?

Comment: Hi, can anybody help me with this? :)